# RESTful API authentication and further requests

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, authentication

I wrote a RESTful API in java in which the client has to create an account (POST to /user) and then login (POST to /login).

Now I am creating a frontend for the web-browser using AngularJS. The problem is, when I create a user, try to login and enter some login-secured-url's, I get

401 Unauthorized

It seems like every request should be authenticated separately, am I right ?

### **Steps I made:**

1. POST to /user which creates a user
2. POST to /login which logs in the user
3. GET to /account/1/something which is login-secured path in my REST service, it returns 401

When I was writing the REST service, I was testing everything under RESTful WebService test-client in IntelliJ IDEA and it was and still is all right there.

What is the way to solve this problem ?

@Neo
Here you have **RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler**

```
@Component("successHandler")
public class RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authentication)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

        if (savedRequest == null) {
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
            return;
        }
        final String targetUrlParameter = getTargetUrlParameter();
        if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl() || (targetUrlParameter != null && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParameter)))) {
            requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
            return;
        }

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

    public void setRequestCache(final RequestCache requestCache) {
        this.requestCache = requestCache;
    }
}
```

I have also another classes, but the post would become too wordy if I added it all, so please let me know if you (suggesting a classname) need code of any of these below:
[image: config classes list]

Comment: You will have to add some code to let me take a look for problems... Also you need to explain how your authentication works?!? Do you send a Cookie? Or a token? Without to know how you authenticate and reidentify the client requests after authentication, there is no Chance to help you :-)

Comment: @Neo I realised that I have no idea which method I use.. :) I suppose that authentication is cached and thats why a client should be able to do many requests after /login just once. If you need any other code let me know as soon as possible